# How are setters used with mutable objects?

Tags: c#

As I understand, setters in C# are meant to enforce business logic and preserve some invariant. But that seems to be incompatible with the fact that most classes are mutable and getters hand out references to them. Let's say I have a `Car` class:

```
class Car
{
    public Car(int maxSpeed)
    {
        _maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
    }

    public void UpgradeEngine()
    {
        _maxSpeed += 50;
    }

    private int _maxSpeed;

    public int max_speed
    {
        get => _maxSpeed;
    }
}
```

and I have a `SchoolDriver` class, which is not allowed to have a car with higher max speed than 200:

```
class SchoolDriver
{
    private Car _schoolBus = new Car ( 200 );
    public Car SchoolBus
    {
        get => _schoolBus;
        set
        {
            if (value.max_speed <= 200)
                _schoolBus = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Sure, you can't assign a new car that doesn't meet the requirement, but you can easily change max speed of the existing car:

```
class Program
{
    public static int Main()
    {
        SchoolDriver d = new SchoolDriver();
        d.SchoolBus = new Car(250); // Won't change the car.
        d.SchoolBus.UpgradeEngine(); // Will change the speed

        return 0;
    }
}
```

This seems to break the invariant, and the encapsulation. It's going to be hard to enforce any kind of invariant, short of wrapping the `Car` class in an immutable class.

My question: What's a valid use case for setters with mutable objects and reference semantics? How can I enforce stuff like "SchoolDriver cannot have a car faster than 200 max speed"?

In C++, I'd return a const-refence, which (semantically) cannot be muted without some evil `const_cast`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper approach in this case is, in fact, making the `Car` class immutable:

```cs
class Car
{
    public Car(int maxSpeed)
    {
       max_speed = maxSpeed;
    }
    public int max_speed
    {
        get;
    }
}
```

The max speed of a car doesn't normally change once the car has been built, so it is pretty reasonable to make that a read-only property.

To be on the save side, when you do have a mutable object (and cannot change that), it is best to not expose it directly at all.

```cs
class SchoolDriver
{
    private Car _schoolBus = new Car ( 200 );
    public void UpgradeCarEngine()
    {
        if (_schoolBus.max_speed < 150)
           _schoolBus.UpgradeEngine();
    }
}
```

Consider also this common mistake:

```cs
public class PersonList
{
    private List<string> _names;
    public PersonList()
    {
         _names = new List<string>();
    }

    public List<string> Names => _names; // This property is read-only, isn't it?
    public void Add(string name)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            _names.Add(name);
        }
    }
}
```

The property `Names` is read-only, but that does not prevent using it to add invalid entries to the list.

Luckily, the framework has the read-only wrappers built-in:

```cs
    public IReadOnlyList<string> Names => _names.AsReadOnly();
```

Downside of course is that every access to the property creates a new object.

Comment: Car was a simple example. You could have a class that, if mutated, won't meet your requirements, so you don't want to be mutable by literally everyone else. I could wrap that class in a non-mutable wrapper, but that is a bit too much work for every class I use.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Providing a mutable wrapper is one solution, but first you need to ask whether you want the `ScoolDriver` to expose its `Schoolbus` property at all. Make that property private and no one will mess with it.

Comment: Well, then we would be talking about a private field, not a public property.

Comment: You'd probably use a field, not a property, yes. But semantically that doesn't make a difference. If you need to expose some features of the Schoolbus, you could expose _them_ instead of the full object (i.e. add a `SchoolBusSpeed` property on the `ScoolDriver` class, which could do the testing)

Comment: Yes, that would be appropriate. But then you're not using a setter. My point is that I don't understand how the whole setter concept fits in with mutable objects.

Comment: Perhaps the point is that setters are meant to be only used with immutable objects, and you're not supposed to expose mutable objects. That does make sense.

Comment: Yes, that's basically the concept. A class should make sure it only exposes methods and properties which don't allow changing the internal state in an unexpected way.